# c# Killing AsyncCaller Thread

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous

I am writing a windows forms application and I have a procedure that i run in another thread with AsyncCaller as follows:

```
asyncCaller = new AsyncCaller(myProcedure);
asyncCaller.BeginInvoke(null, null);
```

I want to kill the thread if the user wants to quit the form. So how can I manually force the thread to kill itself even if it is not completed ?

Comment: What is the namespace of AsyncCaller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usally an asynchronus Thread should en itself by end of execution. What you can do is, to set flag which get periodically gets checked in the thread (not recommended).
The best Solution is to use the Thread Class, which gives you more control of your running Thread,